# Htaccess rewrite rule code

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with htaccess. I tried to set the links from http://website.tld/index.php?a=profile&u=name to http://website.tld/name

The htaccess file already had this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

I added:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]
```

and it's not working. what should i add to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your new rewrite rule should come before the last one since it matches `/name` too.

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a file then stop processing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L]
```

Your last `RewriteRule`s is far more complex than it needs to be. For example, `([^/]*)+` should just be `[^/]+`. If you provide more details about what its trying to match I can advise some simplification.

Comment: Removing your comments from 1st 2 lines otherwise 500 error might still come.

Comment: @anubhava, even that request uri check is kinda not required 'coz filename check should catch it.

Comment: @DragosCosmin, do you still get 500 with the updates?